# Help an idiot gain confidence / know what to do after a TWRP Data wipe

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, twrp, magisk

I rooted my phone sometime mid-2018 or something, just followed some instructions somewhere on how to root. Right now I have TWRP and Magisk on this phone.

Currently, I have a strange dilemma with the phone lagging on certain apps that my other devices like an Asus Zenfone 5 would not. I figured that it might be time for a reset.

Before I rooted my phone, this was pretty easy; backup everything, use the OS' Factory Reset functionality, wait for everything to boot up again, then put only what you want back in.

Now with root however, I've been doing a bunch of reading throughout my free time for the week and I still have a bunch of questions unanswered. But I really wanna unclog this device as soon as I can.

1. Is my understanding correct that, because I'm on TWRP, I should use TWRP's Wipe -> Data instead of just the Android OS' Factory Setting Reset functionality?
2. After I wipe the Data, can I just do the same thing I did unrooted and wait for the OS to boot up and set everything up again? If no, then what should I do (flashing, etc)? If yes, then do I automatically get Magisk back as part of the OS' 'reinstallation' or is there another set of instructions that I have to follow to get Magisk again?
3. Before I do anything, I understand that I should crated a Nandroid backup. But I don't have an SD card for this. After creating the backup, should I then transfer the backup to a separate storage away from the phone before performing the data wipe, or can I keep it wherever TWRP saves it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright, to downvoters: please say why you downvoted, Its more useful. As for the question itself, what phone is it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to find an image (zip) of the Rom you have now, wether it's the stock one or a custom one (Use xdadevelopers to find your phone in the advanced search, and then head to android development for your phone)
At this point you should also grab a new (updated) zip of magisk.
[Stock roms are usually found in the general forum for your phone, in a stickied (pinned to the top) post]

Make a TWRP backup, which will only backup your system and apps, not your data. Move that to your computer either by rebooting back to android or enabling adb in TWRP.

Move the selected Rom, gapps and magisk zips to your phone storage, and select WIPE > selecting both caches, system and data. Not the internal storage. You should also use the inbuilt file manager to nuke the Android folder.

After that completes, follow your Rom installation instructions on the xda forum post (usually flashing Rom + Gapps (which they should specify, if not get opengapps the minimal version like pico or the one above it). Sometimes you'll have to flash a patch with the Rom too). When the Rom+Gapps install finishes reboot into system. This will help you diagnose if the system fails to boot at the end of this reinstall. If everything is good go back to TWRP and flash magisk. You are done now. Don't forget to open the magisk app when you reboot to finish the setup.

If you fail to boot after Rom+gapps, go back and wipe both caches, system and data (leaving internal data), then try installing just the Rom. If it fails, find a new Rom. If the Rom is good, then you need a smaller gapps package, or a different one. I think slimgapps are good too, but I've never had opengapps fail on me.

Gl